# Extract data from mongoid into Rails fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there a way to save data from my local development environment (running `Rails 3` and `mongoid`) into fixtures or a dump file for later reimport into my production environment? As far as I have seen `rake db:dump` does not work with `mongoid`.

**update:** to further clarify what I am trying to do: sometimes it would be nice to add live data (which will be used in the production site too) directly when developing a project to work with real data instead of seeded samples. It would be nice to have a feature (e.g. `rake` task) to dump this data into a file and then re-import it with `rake` on the production server.

Comment: at the moment I do it with `mongodump` and `mongorestore` manually but that is a bit tedious

Comment: Can you edit your question with some more info? How much data are we talking about? Is it a one time thing or you need to do it from time to time?

Comment: xlembouras: please look at my comment to your answer, though I will update the question too.

Answer (score 1):

You can have some data on your `db/seeds.rb` file and use `rake db:seed` command to import them. See [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/rails.html#rake)

`db/seeds.rb` is mainly used for some basic data, not a whole database. If you want to migrate a full db you should do it manually with [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) commands.

*UPDATE*

Having production data to your development environment can be tricky.

If your data are not that big you can set up a periodic operation to put a snapshot of production to your development db.

If your db is big (eg some hundreds of MBytes or even GB) you will not be able to have everything in development easily and frequently updated. In that case I think you will need to decide which data are needed and fetch some of them by different criteria each time.

eg fetch collection x or fetch 1000 records from collection x

Of course all these are too general for an answer. You need to examine exactly what is the minimum set that fits your needs and try to satisfy that.

Comment: thank you - I use `rake db:seed` for initially seeding my database with sample data but I was looking for an easy way to add live data in development and not have to re-add it into production once I am deploying my site by means of `mongodump/-restore`. This is a "nice-to-have" thing though ;)

Comment: @StefanSchuchlenz I get it, I added some things.